# Initialization of global variable requires a constant value

Tags: maya, mel

I've been trying to find an answer to this problem for some time now and I still can't find the root to my problem.

I'm working with procedures in `maya (mel)`, and I'm having a really hard time being able to use `global variables` as a means to work with saving data between different procedures.

My main problem is represented here:

In the first example I can replace the already declared `global variable` inside a procedure as I need it to be.

But then in the second example when trying to change the value of the `global variable` it says the procedure needs a constant value.

Also, I've tried making a `local variable` only to pass it later on to the `global variable`, yet I still get the same problem.

```
global string $value[];

proc test()
{
    global string $value[] = {"door", "knob"};
    print ($value);

}

test();

//Result: door, knob



global string $value[];

proc test()
{
    global string $value[] = `ls -sl`;
    print ($value);

}

test();

//Result: Initialization of global variable "$value" requires a constant value.
```

Waiting for possible solutions, been searching for a lot now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the second proc instead:

```
 global string $value[];
 $value = `ls -sl`;
```

The message is telling you the problem --  `ls -sl` is not a constant value, it will be different every time. so you can't use it as the *initial* value of the the global  - the proc does not know that `$value` exists yet, so it's trying to create a new one and MEL does not want you to create a new global with a non-constant value.

It's good practice in any case not to declare and fill a global at the same time unless you plan on leaving it constant or want  predictable default value.  That's why MEL wants you to separate declaration from assignment.

Comment: wow! I feel like a noob now... thanks a ton! you really helped me out

Comment: If that fixes the problem you should mark the answer accepted so future googlers know it works